# Mongoid: Added Hash to Model but can't write to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I've got a model, Entity.

```
class Entity
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :x
  field :y
  field :z, type => Hash, :default => {} # new field

end
```

I added a new field to it, a hash. When I try to use it, I get an error. My code is:

```
e = Entity.first
if e.z["a"] # if there is a key of this in it?
  e.z["a"] = e.z["a"] + 1
else
  e.z["a"] = 1
end
```

But, this error with an undefined method get for hash.  If I try to create an initializer for it, to set the values in an existing document, it errors with the same error.  What am I doing wrong?

Initializer looks like:

```
e = Entity.first
e.write_attribute(:z, {})
```

Thanks

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for {}:Hash
 from /Users/wflanagan/sites/marketfu/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/mongoid-7b3cfd92c5ab/lib/mongoid/field.rb:50:in `get'
 from /Users/wflanagan/sites/marketfu/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/mongoid-7b3cfd92c5ab/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:64:in `read_attribute'
 from /Users/wflanagan/sites/marketfu/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/mongoid-7b3cfd92c5ab/lib/mongoid/fields.rb:55:in `block in create_accessors'
 from /Users/wflanagan/sites/marketfu/app/models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it.

It seems the answer is to set in Mongoid 1.9.5 the hash to:

```
field :hash_field, :type => Hash, :default => Hash.new
```

and it can access and initialize it. Not quite understanding why, but happy to have the answer !

Comment: Normally, the field is initialized to `nil`. Additionally, there is not `Hash#get()` method in ruby.

Comment: It was Mongo 1.9X that had this problem. Upgrading to 2.0+ seems to have solved it.